# Grails 2.4 named configuration for JSON not working

Tags: json, spring, grails, groovy

I can't use a specified named config to render object as JSON. What i'm doing wrong?

I defined a named config in Bootstrap.groovy init method

```
import com.appromocodes.Project
import com.appromocodes.Promocode
import grails.converters.JSON

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->


        JSON.createNamedConfig('apiCheck', {
            JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Promocode) { Promocode promocode ->
                def map= [:]
                map['code'] = promocode.code
                map['allowedUses'] = promocode.allowedUses
                map['customInfo'] = promocode.customInfo

                return map              
              }
        })

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Then i have a classic controller (not REST, but simple controller):

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class ApiV1Controller {

def apiV1Service

    def check() {

        log.info("check");

        def resultMap = apiV1Service.checkPromocode(params.projectKey, params.code)


        if (resultMap.statusCode != ResponseStatus.PROMOCODE_USED) {
        }

        def p = Promocode.get(1)

        JSON.use('apiCheck', {
            render p as JSON
        })

    }

}
```

I would expect that invocation of check action would output only the three properties specified in apiCheck named config, instead i get all the bean properties and also the metaClass properties "class" and "id".

If i don't specify a named config, then JSON renders correctly the bean showing only three properties.

What is wrong? Is it possible to use namedConfig also in non REST controllers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DefaultConverterConfiguration`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/converters/configuration/DefaultConverterConfiguration.html) as JSON with default config is passed on to the closure as a parameter. [That configuration has to be used to `registerObjectMarshaller`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/grails/converters/JSON.java#L439). So the closure has to be implemented as below (note the param to the closure).

```
JSON.createNamedConfig('apiCheck', { config ->
     config.registerObjectMarshaller(Promocode) { Promocode promocode ->
         def map= [:]
         map['code'] = promocode.code
         map['allowedUses'] = promocode.allowedUses
         map['customInfo'] = promocode.customInfo

         return map              
     }
})
```

An easier, clear and groovier implementation would be:

```
JSON.createNamedConfig( 'apiCheck' ) { 
     it.registerObjectMarshaller( Promocode ) { Promocode promocode ->
         [ 
             code        : promocode.code, 
             allowedUses : promocode.allowedUses,
             customInfo  : promocode.customInfo
         ]
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. I read the doc but misunderstood how to use it with named configurations!

Comment: @GiorgioAndretti No worries. Glad to know you read the docs. :)