# How to have several custom JSON marshaller for a class

Tags: json, grails

I need to have several custom JSON marshallers since i want to marshall in different ways for differentpurposes. I know how to set a custom marshaller application wide using:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(MyClass) {
...
}
```

But this hooks me with this particular definition.

How can i create an adhoc marshaller for, let's say, just one method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have [Named Configuration for Object Marshallers](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#namedObjectMarshallers). [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574172/2051952) I recently came across.

```
JSON.createNamedConfig( 'myDesiredApi' ) { 
     it.registerObjectMarshaller( SomeDomain ) { SomeDomain someDomain ->
         // Desired response map
     }
}
```

When rendering response the usage would be like:

```
JSON.use( 'myDesiredApi' ) {
    render someDomain as JSON
}
```

Comment: Shameless plug: if you have many named marshallers you can make their definition easier using domain class annotations with my [Grails Json Apis](http://grails.org/plugin/json-apis) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is used for one method you can simply generate a JSON using Groovy JsonBuilder utility:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
response {
    property1 myClass.property1
    property2 myClass.property2
}
response.toPrettyString()
```

Will output:

```
{
    "property1" : "value_1",
    "property2" : "value_2"
}
```